# Explanation regarding phtml coding in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, phtml, magento-2.0.2

When I explored the header links and footer links inside the files of Magento 2, the links are declared like each in one seperate `default.xml` file inside individual modules. But the links are displayed in same block at frontend as list elements. 
The `phtml` coding is different from Magento 1.9.x. My doubt is how they are grouping the seperately declared blocks (in `default.xml`) and displaying in frontend as a single block elements (list) using `phtml` files.

Can someone please explain the concept in easily understandable way. Am a beginner in php coding and newbie to Magento 2.

*Explanation with a sample phtml file example:`footer.phtml` is most welcomed.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, footer.phtml file doesn't seem to be used anywhere, just in single Test class.

But speaking about concept, this is pretty easy :) You can create single block, with single .phtml template file. And by using referenceBlock in other modules you are still working with the same block.

In this situation we have block with `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links` class and `footer_links` name.
In other modules we can add more links to this block by using `<referenceBlock name="footer_links">` and those links will be visible in previously created block. Simple as it. Hope you understood my explaination :)

Comment: what does the line `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>` in `footer.phtml` mean. can you explain that too?

Comment: When you add child blocks to (in this example) footer block, this is the way to output those in your template. This function gets all of them and return in place where you use this function.
You can also pass name as parameter of this function. If you declare two blocks as children, lets say 'child-block-1' and 'child-block-2' by using `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('child-block-1') ?>` you can echo only single of them.

Comment: So do you mean that it does the `grouping` work? ie combining the seperately declared blocks in `default.xml` in one single block with the name `footer` as in above example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `grouping`. In your layout files you can nest blocks. This function returns all blocks that are nested inside your current block, one level below.

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Blocks of all .xml files nested in your one are grouped and returned by this function.

Comment: Yeah that is what I exactly meant. Thank you.  
Does this file have any link with `link.phtml` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.0.2\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this file also doesn't seem to be used anywhere. Links in footer are created by `_toHtml` function of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link` class

Comment: In `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.0.2\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout'  it is like `<referenceContainer name="footer-container">` . Is the name `footer-container` referenced from `footer.phtml` file or anywhere else?

Comment: No, it's defined in `module-theme\view\frontend\page_layout\1column.xml` by `<container name="footer-container">` This is the name you can reference to by `referenceContainer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38845/discussion-between-ramya-and-bartlomiej-szubert).